# Is there a way to reduce computation time while using "ltm" package for a dataset with NULL values

Tags: r, performance

I am using "ltm" package to find the difficulty and discrimination values of questions used in a Computer Adaptive Test conducted among 2400 students.My question bank contains 410 questions out of which 50 are presented to a particular candidate and if the response is correct it is scored as "1" and if wrong it is scored as"0". For the other 360 questions the the cells contains NULL values. The dataset has 2400 rows(candidate id) and 410 columns(questions).

[image: screenshot of dataset]
The ltm function

```
values<-ltm(data~z1,IRT.param = T)
```

takes almost 25 minutes to process this dataset(system specs- 64 bit quadcore i3 3.30GHz, 8GB RAM).
But it takes only a minute to process a dataset of same dimension which does not contain NULL/missing values.
Is there a way to reduce the computation time?
Or can anyone suggest another package which does not have this issue.

Comment: what happens if you run the following: `values<-ltm(data~z1,IRT.param = T, na.action = na.exclude.)`

Comment: It throws the following error--
Error in factor(rs, labels = 1:len.uni) :invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 0
@sanyi14ka